# loop trough object to create containers in dart

Tags: dart

I am coding a website and an app for the same purpose. I am fluent at PHP but new to dart. Both, the website and the app call an API to get the data they should display. In PHP I am using a foreach loop to go through and echo a div for each key just like this:

```
# res is an example string for an api result
$res = '{"first":["ExampleTitle", "ExampleDescription"], "second":["ExampleT2", "ExampleD2"], "third":["ExpampleT3", "ExampleD3"]}';
$res = json_decode($res);

foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
  echo '<div style="margin-bottom: 35px;">'.$value[0].'<br>'.$value[1].'</div>';
}
```

and the output looks like this:

```
ExampleTitle
ExampleDescription

ExampleT2
ExampleD2

ExpampleT3
ExampleD3
```

Now I want to do the same thing in the app using dart. How can I loop trough an object to create multiple containers?

In other words: what dart code would achieve the same thing the PHP code does, except instead of creating divs it creates containers?

Comment: you cant handle html-like data in flutter. your api should return your data as json, and you should convert it in flutter and build the ui accordingly. [you can checkout this page for more info](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Comment: This might help answer your question: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/50360443/10385347>

Comment: @Adnan the data is in the correct json format, thats not the problem but the linked page was still helpful. Thank you!